# Aeson does not find a key that I believe is present

Tags: json, haskell, httpresponse, aeson

I'm trying to parse a JSON blob that looks like this:

```
"{\"order_book\":{\"asks\":[[\"0.06777\",\"0.00006744\"],[\"0.06778\",\"0.01475361\"], ... ]],\"bids\":[[\"0.06744491\",\"1.35\"],[\"0.06726258\",\"0.148585363\"], ...]],\"market_id\":\"ETH-BTC\"}}"
```

Those lists of pairs of numbers are actually much longer; I've replaced their tails with ellipses.

Here's my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Demo where

import Data.Aeson
import Data.ByteString.Lazy hiding (putStrLn)
import Data.Either (fromLeft)
import Network.HTTP.Request

data OrderBook = OrderBook
  { orderBook_asks     :: [[(Float,Float)]]
  , orderBook_bids     :: [[(Float,Float)]]
  , orderBook_marketId :: String
  }

instance FromJSON OrderBook where
  parseJSON = withObject "order_book" $ \v -> OrderBook
    <$> v .: "asks"
    <*> v .: "bids"
    <*> v .: "market_id"

demo :: IO ()
demo = do
  r <- get "https://www.buda.com/api/v2/markets/eth-btc/order_book"
  let d = eitherDecode $ fromStrict $ responseBody r :: Either String OrderBook
  putStrLn $ "Here's the parse error:"
  putStrLn $ fromLeft undefined d
  putStrLn $ "\n\nAnd here's the data:"
  putStrLn $ show $ responseBody r
```

Here's what running `demo` gets me:

```
Here's the parse error:
Error in $: key "asks" not found

And here's the data:
"{\"order_book\":{\"asks\":[[\"0.06777\",\"0.00006744\"],[\"0.06778\",\"0.01475361\"], ... ]],\"bids\":[[\"0.06744491\",\"1.35\"],[\"0.06726258\",\"0.148585363\"], ...]],\"market_id\":\"ETH-BTC\"}}"
```

The "asks" key looks clearly present to me -- it's the first one nested under the "order_book" key.

Comment: It's worth noting that the infelicity explained in the answers really comes down to a mismatch between the JSON and Haskell object model. Haskell records always come with a constructor, which tells you what the structure of the data inside it is. JSON objects are completely anonymous; any labels are actually **field names** of enclosing objects, not constructor/type names of **this** object. So JSON schemas often introduce this sort of extra wrapper, where you have an (anonymous) object with a single field purely to give a label to what sort of data is there.

Comment: So if you uniformly parse JSON object fields into Haskell record fields, you end up needing extra synthetic wrapper types that look pointless at the Haskell level. And you can't uniformly expect to find a JSON field corresponding to the constructor or type, because not every object has that; even though it's common it's far from uniform. So you either make a set of Haskell types that really blindly follow the JSON structure, and then convert that into something more Haskellish, or you write carefully customised parsing logic. Or you just work directly with the weird JSON-like Haskell types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is present, but it's wrapped inside another nested object, so you have to unwrap the outer object before you can parse the keys.

The smallest-diff way to do this is probably just inline:

```hs
instance FromJSON OrderBook where
  parseJSON = withObject "order_book" $ \outer -> do
    v <- outer .: "order_book"
    OrderBook
      <$> v .: "asks"
      <*> v .: "bids"
      <*> v .: "market_id"
```

Though you might want to consider introducing another wrapping type instead. This would really depend on the semantics of the data format you have.

---

I guess you were probably assuming that this is what `withObject "order_book"` would do, but that's not what it does. The first parameter of `withObject` is just a human-readable name of the object being parsed, used to create error messages. Customarily that parameter should name the *type* that is being parsed - i.e. `withObject "OrderBook"`. [See the docs](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.27/aeson-1.5.6.0/Data-Aeson.html#v:withObject).

---

Separately, I think your `asks` and `bids` fields are mistyped.

First, your JSON input looks like they are supposed to be arrays of tuples, but your Haskell type says *doubly nested* arrays of tuples. So this will fail to parse.

Second, your JSON input has strings as elements of those tuples, but your Haskell type says `Float`. This will also fail to parse.

The correct type, according to your JSON input, should be:

```hs
  { orderBook_asks     :: [(String,String)]
  , orderBook_bids     :: [(String,String)]
```

Alternatively, if you really want the floats, you'll have to parse them from strings:

```hs
instance FromJSON OrderBook where
  parseJSON = withObject "order_book" $ \outer -> do
    v <- outer .: "order_book"
    OrderBook
      <$> (map parseTuple <$> v .: "asks")
      <*> (map parseTuple <$> v .: "bids")
      <*> v .: "market_id"
    where
      parseTuple (a, b) = (read a, read b)
```

(note that this ☝️ code is not to be copy&pasted: I'm using `read` for parsing strings into floats, which will crash at runtime if the strings are malformatted; in a real program you should use a better way of parsing)

Comment: Crushed it. Thanks, Fyodor!

Answer (score 3):

`withObject "order_book"` does not look into the value at key `"order_book"`. In fact, the `"order_book"` argument is ignored apart from appearing in the error message; actually you should have `withObject "OrderBook"` there.

All `withObject` does is confirm that what you have *is* an object. Then it proceeds using that object to look for the keys `"asks"`, `"bids"` and `"market_id"` – but the only key that's there at this level is `order_book`.

The solution is to only use this parser with the `{"asks":[["0.06777"...]...]...}` object. The `"order_book"` key tells no information anyway, unless there are other keys present there as well. You can represent that outer object with another Haskell type and its own `FromJSON` instance.